# How to test the significance of plm estimation used for diff-in-diff application

Tags: statistical-significance, p-value, linear-model, panel-data, covariance-matrix

Good morning,

I used panel linear model estimation taking into account a generalized diff-in-diff approach. Using R and the function plm I set a two way fixed effects regression with time and unit fixed effects.

The formula of my regression is:

Y= ft+gi+adit+e

where ft=fixed effects for times(anno),gi= fixed effects for cases(comuni, a is the coefficient, dit=is the dummy variable and e standard errors

I have a panel data composed by Italian villages(Comune) and observations for years (Anno) from 2003 to 2019 with different treatment starting times.

the plm code that I used is the following:

```
didregfe<-plm(Y ~ did, index = c("Comune", "Anno"), method = "within", effect = "twoways", data = mydata)
```

Those are my results:

for the first dependent variable

Coefficients:
Estimate Std. Error t-value Pr(>|t|)
did   49.630     23.543  2.1081  0.03522 *

for the second dependent variable

Coefficients:
Estimate Std. Error t-value Pr(>|t|)
did   219.82      92.30  2.3816  0.01738 *

Thus, the results are positive and the  the generic coeftest that come out from the measurement shows significant values for both coefficients.

My first question is:

Can I consider the generic coeftest as a good method to test the significance and reliability of my evaluation?

Then I used the command vcovHC in order to know the robust covariance matrix of parameters for my fixed effects model.

the code that I use is:

```
>coeftest(didregfe,vcov.=vcovHC, type="HC1")
```

and for the two variables my results are not significant:

t test of coefficients:

```
Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
```

did    49.63      55.25  0.8983   0.3692

Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
did   219.82     176.85   1.243   0.2141

Concluding in order to cluster the standard errors at case level I used this code, but also in this case the results are not significant:

```
coeftest(didregfe,vcov=vcovHC(didregfe, typw="sss", cluster="group"))
```

t test of coefficients:

```
  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
```

did   49.630     55.593  0.8927   0.3722

```
  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
```

did   219.82     177.94  1.2353   0.2169

So, taking into account that the evaluation of robustness of regressions failed, Can I use as well the model plm that I introduced above?
Did I use the right codes to evaluate the robust covariance matrix and to cluster the standard errors at case level?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: What is a “case” in the context of your study? Is it individuals? Does your data have a nested structure? It would also be nice to see the formula you used to estimate the regression in `plm`.

Comment: The context of my study is a diff-in-diff analysis with n cases that are cities, with observation of times from 2003 to 2019 and different starting time of treatment application. The plm code is: plm(y ~ did, index = c("comune", "anno"), method = "within", effect = "twoways", data = mydata). So I will edit these info in the question. Thanks!